# Recommendations for a good Modelling tool for ipad

Tags: mysql, database-design

Apologies if this question is not allowed - but I couldn't even find the search box on the site to search for answers!

I'd like recommendations for a good database modelling tool that works on an ipad (natively ideally - rather than a web-based tool). I use Navicat on my Mac which is great - but no option to write/edit models in the ipad version.

Thanks in advance, and apologies if off-topic/inappropriate. (Recommendation for where i can ask the question in that case!)

Comment: In Flemish we have a saying "what use are candle and glasses, if the owl doesn't want to see?".  In my browser the search box is on the top line of this site, and it says "Search on Database Administrators".   https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-D60VGdwbC1Y/WhmV7Ju3IaI/AAAAAAAAjUY/0C28zzTJBMchHoESbyytk-LVR7_LTMPLgCLcBGAs/s320/23722593_287688155074487_7761824554333196377_n.jpg

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! For better or worse, product recommedations are considered off-topic here and your question will likely be closed as a "shopping list" or similar! There is a software_recommedations site - you'd be better off asking there. Good luck...

Comment: Thank you for the answers... I can see the search box now. I blame my dark mode browser!! And probably lack of glasses.

Comment: And apologies for being off-topic.